# iPad Safari does not fire blur event

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari

I have an html input text element in my application with jQuery blur event handler:

```
$('#textBox').blur(function () { console.log('blur'); })
```

When I click on a page area out of the textbox, desktop browsers fire this event, but iPad Safari does not. And neither the keyboard nor the cursor does not disappear. Are there any ways to "enable" the blur event ?

Comment: NO,you have to focus on another element.or just <body ontouchstart="..." onclick="..."></body>

Comment: can you edit your question whether you have achieved it (If yes, please update with answer ) or not ?

Comment: @RahulDess oh, I really don't remember since it was 3 years ago, but looks like i haven't because none of answers were suggested any more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design, a tap away will remove the hover state but the textbox will remain focused.

[Safari Web Content Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) should help you develop for Safari on IOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround (albeit not recommended): https://codepen.io/kevinfarrugia/pen/rKpRBL

```
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("container").focus();
});
```