# How to make bootstrap sticky footer work on android?

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer

The [bootstrap sticky navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/) example states it applies to "desktop browsers". That example does work well on my desktop. My question: how do I make it work on android WebView? When I try opening it, the footer doesn't stick. Instead, it is added below the content section:

[image]

Comment: `position:fixed` on Android webview has been a problem. [Here's an answer (2-years-old) that probably still relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22710829/3585500).

Comment: Can you please add your code to fiddle or code snippet

Comment: The code is the one already provided in the bootstrap link above, I didn't change a thing... I'll check the metadata thing shortly