# position:fixed sliding bug in Chrome Mobile

Tags: html, css

If  you view [my website](http://alexander-pastor.de) in Chrome Mobile on a mobile phone and scroll in any direction, the footer wouldn't stay put. Any idea for the cause or a fix?

The CSS code of the footer looks like the following:

```
#footer{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;

    filter:...;

    margin:0;
    padding:0;

    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;

    z-index:3000;
}
```

The initially shown part of the footer would be #pull2 with the following CSS properties:

```
#pull2 {

    width: 100%;

    display: block;
    position:static;
    float:none;

    padding-left:10px;

    z-index:0;

    background: ...;
    background-position:...;
    cursor:pointer;

}

#pull2 p{

    line-height: 40px;
    margin:0;

}
```

Comment: Its position: fixed not absolute...

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254146/position-fixed-not-working-in-mobile-browser

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried this just now! Didn't help though, even *{-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;} hasnt helped. The mistake might be somewhere else i suspect.

Answer (score 16):

Try adding;

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

with `position: fixed`.

**Ref:**

[Easy CSS fix for fixed positioning](http://benfrain.com/easy-css-fix-fixed-positioning-android-2-2-2-3/)
[Position fixed not working in mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254146/position-fixed-not-working-in-mobile-browser)

---

Alternatively you can achieve this with jQuery

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/TbMv4/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var winHeight = $(window).height();

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $("#footer").css("top", $(window).scrollTop() + (winHeight-30) + "px");
    });

});
```

Comment: No luck for me in Android 9 on backface-visibility. Causing glitches.

Comment: I had to add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0"/> to have it working.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` trick, having an element larger than the page seems to also cause issues with `position: fixed` (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520335/position-fixed-100-isnt-viewport-width-when-a-bigger-div-is-present-on-the-pag)). It may also be worth adding `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">` to your `<head>` tag.

Comment: Disabling user scaling of a page isn't the greatest idea. If user can't read something, they will try to scale, and if they can't, they will only get angry :)

Comment: I agree, it's best to avoid disabling the user's scaling ability whenever possible. But I wanted to share my solution to the problem, because it struck me as being so obscure. Perhaps I ought to update my answer with a note about only using that meta tag in the absolute worst-case scenario?

Comment: Worst, or a very special case (e.g. if you are simulating "desktop" or other non-web app)

Comment: Interestingly, even having an element wider than the current page causes this in Chrome Mobile on Android and Chrome Desktop mobile emulation. Chrome on iOS and all Firefox are unaffected. The solution is to fix your element so it does not go beyond the width of a page, then everything works fine. How the two are connected is beyond me but it works.

Comment: Its fine to disable scaling if you provide other font-sizing methods in the UI

Comment: Thanks @CaspianRoach, this was my issue. I had multiple nested Twitter Boostrap .row/.col-xs-12 divs and the many -15px neg margins and 15px paddings didn't exactly get-along and one of my nested col-xs-12 was bigger than my .row. So fixed that, and seems to work now.

Comment: No need to put user-scalable to no. But adding <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0"/> fixed the issue for me, as long as default scale is used