# clickable phone button .svg stylesheet not clicking

Tags: html, css, mobile

Hello Im having problems on a mobile phone for it to be able to touch call the number under the image. the image is being called from the stylesheet. It works fine on chrome desktop but on the mobile the green call button (bottom right) isnt working nicely on mobile. IT seems not to be sitting at the top of the page as well.

site: bittersweetcafe.com.au

```css
.callnowbutton {
  
    width: 100px;
    right: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
    border-top-left-radius: 40px;
    height: 80px;
    bottom: -20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #2dc62d;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) center 2px no-repeat #090;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-size: 58px 58px;
    position:fixed;
    
}
```

```html
   <a href="tel:0394974144">
<div class="callnowbutton">
 
</div></a>
```

Comment: I notice you are not specifying display:block; or display:table; which may help. Also position:fixed; can be problematic on mobile devices.

Comment: also and a tag inside a div makes more sense than an a tag wrapping a div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
<div class="callnowbutton">
    <a href="tel:0394974144"></a>
</div>
```

According to [http://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19254147/4592215) you need to add "-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;" to your **.callnowbutton** class:

```
.callnowbutton {
    /* your code here */
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}
```

It could help to:

```
.callnowbutton a {
    display: block; 
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```