# position:fixed moves on mobile scroll

Tags: css, mobile, css-position

I'm working on a website where on certain pages I want to have a fixed bar on the top of the page. On mobile this functions but when the finger is released from screen the bar moves away from the screen.

I've been using position:fixed;, top:0; and display:block;

Is there any way to fix this? 
I've been twisting my brains around it for the last couple of days but can't seem to get it working.

[edit; In this

```css
/* Basic CSS */

#offcanvas-menu {
  z-index: 99999;
}

.banner {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: auto;
  border-bottom-width: 0.13vw;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

.banner_inner {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0.3%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.banner {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: white;
  translateY(100%);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  z-index: 102;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* main text in bar */

#banner-inner {
  margin-left: 1.5%;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  min-height: 144px;
  position: relative;
}

#banner-row-1 {
  width: 15vw;
  margin-right: 1.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

#banner-row-2 {
  width: 15vw;
  margin-right: 1.5%;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 17.7vw;
}

#banner-row-3 {
  width: 46.02vw;
  margin-right: 1.5%;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 34.18740849194729vw;
}

#banner-row-3 p6 {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.39vw;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

a4 {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.39vw;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

a5 {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.39vw;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

#banner h4 {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 3.2vw;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1.5%;
  margin-top: 1.2vw;
  margin-bottom: 1.2vw;
  width: 31.5vw;
}

#banner h5 {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 3.2vw;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 34.18740849194729vw;
  margin-top: 1.2vw;
  margin-bottom: 1.2vw;
  margin-left: 1.5%;
  width: 46.02vw;
}

#banner h6 {
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 3.2vw;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 34.18740849194729vw;
  margin-top: 1.2vw;
  margin-bottom: 1.2vw;
  margin-left: 1.5%;
  width: 15.1vw;
}


/* left */

nav#offcanvas-menu {
  /* Full screen nav menu */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 29.5vw;
  /* this is for browsers that don't support CSS3 translate3d */
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -23.3vw, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -23.3vw, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -23.3vw, 0);
}

nav#offcanvas-menu {
  left: 0vw;
}


/* off canvas sidebar left right */

div#main-region {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
  /* transition settings */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}


/*SIDEBAR LEFT*/

input[type="checkbox"]#togglebox {
  /* checkbox used to toggle menu state */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

nav#offcanvas-menu label#closex {
  /* Large x close button inside nav */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -10000px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]#togglebox:checked~nav#offcanvas-menu {
  /* nav state when corresponding checkbox is checked */
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  visibility: visible;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

nav#offcanvas-menu {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 104;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  overflow: auto;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
  /* transition settings */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<label for="togglebox">
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="togglebox" />
<nav id="offcanvas-menu">
  <label for="togglebox" id="closex">×</label>
  <label for="togglebox">
  <div id="banner-inner">
    <div id="banner-row-1">
      <a4>Client</a4><br>
      <a5>Client name</a5><br><br>
      <a4>Year</a4><br>
      <a5>2016</a5><br><br>
      <a4>Collaboration</a4><br>
      <a5>Name Person</a5>
    </div>
    <div id="banner-row-2">
      <a4>Specifications</a4><br>
      <a5>specifications</a5>  
    </div>
    <div id="banner-row-3">
      <p6>piece of text<p6><br><br>
      <p6>piece of text</p6>  
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner" id="banner">
    <h4>Titel project</h4>
    <h5>Identity, Typography, Web</h5>
    <h6>↓ Info</h6>
  </div>
  </label>
</nav>
<br><br><br><br><br>Test<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Test<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Test<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Test<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Test<br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Please post relevant code here. So we don't have to go to your website, inspect it, and figure out where we should even be looking.

Comment: Problem is, originally I wrote this on codepen where it worked but after implementing it didn't function anymore.

Comment: you have transform3d and the Y is set to some negative value

Comment: @Huangism I needed this so the information bar will slide out

Comment: @LuudJacobs the code is added above, here it does work while scrolling. On phone it doesn't...

Comment: @Marcel Unrelated to the question, but you have an opening `<p6>` tag where there should be a closing one (`</p6>`). And are the `<a1>` and `<p1>` tags formal HTML?

Comment: Possibly related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254146/position-fixed-not-working-in-mobile-browser and https://stackoverflow.com/a/4889749/2397327

Comment: @LambdaNinja I've edited this in the final one, thanks for pointing out ^^

Comment: @LambdaNinja I've tried these two options but chrome developer tools don't recognise these... So i thought that it wouldn't function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `translate3d` from one of the parents (`div#main-region`), or else your position fixed will be based on that translate3d parent