# How to fix a moving navbar bottom mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I develop an application mobile in html/css/php and I'm using bootstrap 3.
I fixed a navbar in bottom for being my navigation, but when I'm scrolling, my navbar moving a lot and I can't see the writing below my icons. 
But, but, maybe it's the console of chrome who doing this ? And in phone that doesn't moving no ?

My code css :

```
.navbarMobile {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
   z-index: 2;
 }
```

My code html :

```
<div class="navbarMobile">
    <div class="col-xs-3 no-padding">
        <a href="#home" class="active"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><p 
        class="menuTitle">Accueil</p></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 no-padding">
        <a href="#news"><i class="fas fa-folder"></i> <p 
        class="menuTitle">Documents</p></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 no-padding">
       <a href="#contact"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> <p 
       class="menuTitle">Boutique</p></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3 no-padding">
       <a href="#contact"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><p 
       class="menuTitle">Compte</p></a>
    </div>  
 </div>
```

My result :

Scrolling Up :
https://zupimages.net/up/19/21/fqos.jpg

Scrolling Down :
https://zupimages.net/up/19/21/21b2.jpg

Comment: There must be more code involved. Can you create a fiddle, or provide a link to a test page?

Comment: Fixed position has many issues in mobile devices. But have you tried this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254146/position-fixed-not-working-in-mobile-browser

Comment: Thx for your feedback. 
I think it's impossible to you to resolve this problem because that was in other css and I never never thinks that modify the code. 
Hmm an other developer change the property of h2 and put a width: 100% on him. I don't know why he doing that but thats break my block. 

Thx for ur answers guys

Answer (score -2):

Sidebars are often relative to their parent elements. So the display attribute is default relative.
Try, this one: Adding this one to your sidebar's css

```
position: fixed
```