# Jquery scroll issue on ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some Jquery code that makes a div sticky on scroll down and scroll up. It seems to be fine on desktop, problem is when I test on iphone and scroll up and get to the top of the page it still applies the `.sticky` class, which is should not. Is this an issue with the device, known issue? This is my code:

**CSS**

```
.sticky {
  top: 44px!important;
  position:fixed;
}

.sticky2 {
  top: 88px!important;
  position:fixed;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(event){

   var $src = $('.fixed');

   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
      $src.last().addClass("sticky");
      $src.last().removeClass("sticky2");

   } else {
      $src.last().removeClass("sticky");
      $src.last().addClass("sticky2");

   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Position fixed not working in mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254146/position-fixed-not-working-in-mobile-browser)

Comment: No that does not work