# position: fixed; is working on desktop, but not on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

The "position: fixed;" is working in desktop browser, but when I'm viewing my website on my phone it is not working.

[image: desktop]

[image: phone]

This is my css:

```
.mobileNavigation {
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}
```

And this is my html:

```
<div class="mobileNav">
    <a href="#" class="navLink">Home<div class="underline"></div></a>
    <a href="#" class="navLink">About us</a>
    <a href="#" class="navLink">Gallery</a>
    <a href="#" class="navLink navBtn">Contact</a>
</div>
```

I tried to add "-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;" but it didn't help me

Comment: Please check your code. What is mobileNav/Navigation.

Comment: Yeah, the class name is not matching. please check carefully.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Position fixed not working in mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254146/position-fixed-not-working-in-mobile-browser)